# How to make a <li> clickable from ajax search results returning dynamic html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax to search a database when a user starts typing in the text field. Results show up in an unordered list. I want them to be able to click on a list item and that item must appear in the text box. I have the search working and the list displaying but I am struggling with the clicking on the li part.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" id="name">
  <div class="result"></div>
</div>
<div style="display:none" class="loader">
  <img src="../build/css/ajax-loader.gif" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").keyup(function() {
    $(".loader").show();
    var input = $(this).val();
    if (input.length > 3) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'insert-ajax.php',
        data: {
          name: input
        },
        success: function(data) {

          if (!data.error) {
            $(".result").html(data);
            $(".loader").hide();
          }
        }

      });
    }

    if (input.length < 1) {
      $(".loader").hide();
      $(".result").html("");
    }
  });

  $(".result li").click(function() {
    alert($(this).data());
  });

});
```

Comment: @JayBlanchard he has already done that

Comment: I don't think `data()` accepts 0 arguments. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for this.

Since your results are dynamic elements that will be added/removed based on the search query, you cannot bind a click handler on them and should instead bind it to their parent.

A consequence of this is that **any** element within results (so not only `<li>` elements) will trigger this callback when clicked. This means you must filter out elements you do not want to trigger the click.

jQuery's [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method offers a concise way to do both delegation and filtering:

```
// the callback gets called whenever a `li` element within `.result` is clicked
$(".result").on( "click", "li", function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Thank you. If I want to console.log the result, what would I put inside the brackets? console.log()

Comment: @Jonathan no problem. I edited my answer with a logging example.